# Sort list with binary values

Tags: python, sorting

If I have a categorical list with only two values, how can I sort so that the values are placed on after another.

Example:

```
# input list
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']

# expected output
['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

I have a working solution, but I felt like this could be done smarter.
I also looked into `itertools` but could not find anything useful for my problem:

**my solution**:

```
foo = [val for val in lst if val == 'foo']
bar = [val for val in lst if val == 'bar']

lst2 = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(foo, bar)]

final_list = [val for l in lst2 for val in l]

print(final_list)
['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

---

**Note**, the lists always have a equal amount of both values

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first value kept first, you can simply make a list of the first and the other, and multiply as necessary:

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']

first = lst[0]
second = (set(lst) - {first}).pop()
out = [first, second] * (len(lst)//2) 
print(out)
# ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

---

A different, better way of getting the other value, without unnecessarily iterating the whole list to build the set of two values: we just take the next value that is different from the first one.

```
# input list
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']
first = lst[0]
second = next(value for value in lst if value != first)
out = [first, second] * (len(lst)//2) 
print(out)
# ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Tested this on list of 8mil values and your solution was 10x faster than the one from Roadrunner

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating `lst` twice to get `foo` and `bar` into separate lists, you could iterate it once and group the values into a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Then you could flatten the zipped values with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in lst:
    d[item].append(item)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'foo': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'], 'bar': ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']})

print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*d.values()))))
# ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

We could also count the items with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), the multiply the keys as lists by the value counts:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

lst = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo"]

counts = Counter(lst)
# Counter({'foo': 4, 'bar': 4})

print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*([k] * v for k, v in counts.items())))))
# ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Tested both your solutions on list of 8mil values and both were ~10x slower than Thierry's solution. Thank you for the extended answer with links to the documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the * operator to multiply the 2 values as strings:

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']
print(["foo", "bar"] * int(len(lst) / 2))

# ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
```

## How does it work?

`len(lst) / 2`

First, it takes the length of the array, and divides it by two (since we know there are an equal amount of either item, this will always return a whole number).

`int(len(lst) / 2)`

Even though it returns a full number, Python turns division into a float automatically, so you must convert it back using the `int()` operation.

`["foo", "bar"] * int(len(lst) / 2)`

Finally, Python multiplies the 2 values by half of the needed size (2 * 0.5x = x, so you're left with the needed size for the array).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However, you should improve it and make it usable with any pair of values, not only "foo" and "bar". What if you do not know in advance what are the values?

Comment: This is acutally a smart approach, I made your solution bit more general and shorter by doing: `list(set(lst)) * (len(lst) // 2)`

Comment: The question seems to have the `lst` variable as a given, but it would be very easy to replace "foo" and "bar" in the `print` statement, and to replace `len(lst)` with an integer or variable of your choice.

Comment: There is no place in this answer where you get the values from the original data...

Comment: My bad, misunderstood the comment.

Comment: Would've accepted this answer if you edited your answer to make it more general.